# Closure is nil in middleware

Tags: swift, core-location, middleware, swiftui

I working to implement a fluxlike implementation with SwiftUI.

I want to track the location of the user and whenever there is a new location update. Therefore I am using a middleware. The logging and firebase auth middleware is working, but the location tracking is not working. Because newLocation is nil,  however if I put the closure location.newLocation {} in the init of MiddlewareProvider it is posting the location changes. Why is it nil in the middleware?

I included the firebase and logging middleware to show the working middlewares:

```
class VMiddlewareProvider: MiddlewareProvider {

    private var location: TrackLocation

    init() {
        self.location = TrackLocation()

    }

    func provideMiddleware() -> [Middleware<FluxState>] {
        return [
            loggingMiddleware(),
            locationTrackingMiddleware(),
            firebaseMiddleware()
        ]
    }

    private func loggingMiddleware() -> Middleware<FluxState> {
        let loggingMiddleware: Middleware<AppState> = { dispatch, getState in
            return { next in
                return { action in
                    #if DEBUG
                    let name = __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)
                    let queueName = String(cString: name, encoding: .utf8)
                    print("#Action: \(String(reflecting: type(of: action))) on queue: \(queueName ?? "??")")
                    #endif
                    return next(action)
                }
            }
        }
        return loggingMiddleware
    }

    private func locationTrackingMiddleware() -> Middleware<FluxState> {
        let middleware: Middleware<AppState> = { dispatch, getState in
            return { next in
                return { action in
                    switch action as? LocationAction {
                    case .trackLocation:

                        self.location.newLocation = { result in
                            /// never gets called because newLocation is nil
                            print(result)
                        }
                        return next(action)

                    default:
                        return next(action)
                    }
                    return next(action)
                }
            }
        }
        return middleware
    }

    private func firebaseMiddleware() -> Middleware<FluxState> {
        let firebaseMiddleware: Middleware<AppState> = { dispatch, getState in
            return { next in
                return { action in
                    switch action {
                    case let action as AccountActions.Authenticate:
                        let handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener {  (auth, user) in
                            if let user = user {
                                return next(AccountActions.AuthentificationAction(isLoggedIn: true, userUID: user.uid))
                            }  else {
                                return next(AccountActions.AuthentificationAction(isLoggedIn: false, userUID: nil))
                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        return next(action)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return firebaseMiddleware
    }
}
```

The TrackLocation class looks like this:

```
class TrackLocation: NSObject {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var newLocation: ((CLLocation)->())?


    override init() {
        super.init()
        askForPermission()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()
    }

    func checkAuthorisation() {
        askForPermission()
    }

    func askForPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    }

}

extension TrackLocation: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didVisit visit: CLVisit) {
        if let location = manager.location {

            newLocation?(location)

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        newLocation?(locations.last!)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print(status)
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think so? do you debug the middleware?

Comment: yes when the CLLocationManagerDelegate functions get called newLocation is nil, if  I put it in the init it is not nil, the trackLocation Action does get called to the listener should be set right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible bugs:
1.
this function doesn't actually call  `self.location.newLocation`. please, be carefull and debug it.

```
private func locationTrackingMiddleware() -> Middleware<FluxState> {
        let middleware: Middleware<AppState> = { dispatch, getState in
            return { next in
                return { action in
                    switch action as? LocationAction {
                    case .trackLocation:
//// this code isn't called! please,  check
                        self.location.newLocation = { result in
                            /// never gets called because newLocation is nil
                            print(result)
                        }
                        return next(action)

                    default:
                        return next(action)
                    }
                    return next(action)
                }
            }
        }
        return middleware
    }
```

2. Somewhere in your code, you erase this variable: `self.location.newLocation = nil`

BTW, you somewhere can remove the variable `location`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, like I said in the other comment, it is getting called. Making the location property lazy helped.

Comment: you mean removing the location variable from the Middleware provider?